# how to hide a tag which contains "text" as the title

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I want to hide a tag which contain the title as "question" this a tag is not generated by me. so it  does not have a ID.

this is the jQuery i wrote but it seems to be not working

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("a:contain('Question')").hide();
});

</script>
```

can someone help me

Comment: not sure what's your title means here, please paste your html code

Answer (score 1):

You have it almost correct. The selector is "a:contains('Question')"

(It's contains, not contain).

See http://jsfiddle.net/YCCVc/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('selector[title="Question"]').dosomething()
```